# Pandas: if-else not working on a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to define a column in which I want to put 1 or 0 if the date contained in another column is equal to a certain data.

```
DF[['column_i']]= 0 if DF[['column_j']] == '1983-11-08' else 1
```

It seems that the operation is not defined univocally because it returns an error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#150>", line 1, in
> <module>
>     Accounts_conFatt_SR_TRAFF[['Churn']]= 0 if Accounts_conFatt_SR_TRAFF[['Deactive Date']] == '1970-01-01' else 1  
> File "C:\Program
> Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 887, in
> __nonzero__
>     .format(self.__class__.__name__)) ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or
> a.all().
> ```

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

ps= no problems with the types: I have already tried to perform the if on a single DF['column'][0] value and it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this using a `numpy.where` statement:

```
df['column_i'] = np.where(df['column_j'] == '1983-11-08', 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

in this particular case (when you need zero or one) you can do it this way:

```
DF[['column_i']] = (DF[['column_j']] != '1983-11-08').astype(np.int8)
```

using the fact that `True` and `False` values are represented as `1` and `0` internally in Python.

PS but the solution from @reptilicus is more general as you can put there any values not only zero or one.

Comment: ... and in fact I have used yor option this time! :)